# Save cropped area as image

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, browser

I have code that allows me to obtain four coordinates:

initial_x
initial_y
final_x
final_y

This coords form a rectangle which allows to crop the body of a website (all the area within the rectangle). My question is how can you save this cropped area as a file (export it to the machine likewise .jpeg for example) or just allocate memory from the browser to perform this task temporarily? This runs on javascript html and css

Comment: [Check this](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript alone cannot do this. You need to upload an image to the server, along with your packet of coordinate data (which is obtained via a javascript tool), and do the cropping serverside (via something like PHP's [GD](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) library). Once cropped, it is stored on the server, and at that point can be downloaded to the client.

There are a lot of tools to do this (probably not necessary to roll your own from scratch) - heres one:

http://www.webmotionuk.co.uk/php-jquery-image-upload-and-crop-v11

Comment: The kind of info I wanted! Thank you very much :)

Comment: Glad that helps. Shouldn't be too much trouble to implement... 
If you think this answer is helpful upvote or select it as your answer ;)

Comment: I know, sorry I didn't, I had time restriction and forgot that xD ty!